# MySQL 5.7 GENERATED ALWAYS column defined as subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, dynamically-generated

I can't seem to find an issue with my query. I have four tables:

- `agency_info`
- `equipment_taken`
- `equipment_weight`
- `mission_overview`

In mission_overview is a column `totalWeightInKG`, which I want to be calculated by selecting `equipment_taken.qty` (which is INT), and  `equipment_weight.equipWeightInKG` (which is FLOAT), and multiply them.

So far I have this column definition:

```
FLOAT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SELECT qty, equpWeightInKG, (qty*equpWeightInKG) AS totalWeightInKG FROM equipment_taken, equipment_weight) STORED ;
```

I can't get my head around it... Read the documentation on SELECT queries and joins but still can't seem to come up with a right query...

Comment: That is not a query.  In general, *queries* start with `SELECT`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot 'GENERATE' a value from multiple tables, only the table you are currently defining.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I edited the above to say "column definition" where the OP had written "query."

Comment: Note that this discussion applies to 8.0's expressions in INDEX definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html says:

> Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted.

To do what you're trying to do, you'll have to write triggers before INSERT and before UPDATE to query the other tables and populate your float column.

Comment: This seems like the right answer to a reasonable interpretation of the question.